# Why does Xcode push to remote always failed with 'Enter your credentials for the repository on host github.com'

Tags: xcode, git, github

When I push my code to remote repository in Github using XCode, it always failed.

- When I changed my code, I clicked the Commit in Source Contol and then it filed.
- Xcode said that I have no credentials for my own repository!!!!
- Actually, I add the new repository in the XCode Preferences. The https address is from my github account. I am definitely sure that the Github username and password is correct.
- After add the repository in the Preference, I commit the code along with clicking the push to remote.

Here is the error info. Who can tell me why!!
[This is very strange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gGSIC.png)

Comment: How have you solved that problem?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed url in git config file to http version and it helped.